# Multiple open commands oledb connections for querying Excel

Tags: sql, vb.net, excel, performance, oledb

```
Private Function CreateConnString(ByVal Str As String) As String
    Return "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Str & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"""
End Function
...
For Each sMatl_Num As String In alMaterialNumbers
                ifileNo = 1
                dbConnection.ConnectionString = CreateConnString(sExcelDBPath)
                dbCommand.Connection = dbConnection
                dbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT [col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5], [col6] FROM [sheet$] WHERE [material]='" & sMatl_Num & "'" & " AND [col3] IS NOT NULL" & " AND [col6] IS NOT NULL"
                dbConnection.Open()
                dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader()
                If dbReader.HasRows Then
                    Do While dbReader.Read
                        sCol1= dbReader.GetString(0).ToString
                        sCol2= dbReader.GetString(1).ToString
                        sCol3= dbReader.GetString(2).ToString
                        sCol4= dbReader.GetString(3).ToString
                        sCol5= dbReader.GetString(4).ToString
                        sCol6= dbReader.GetString(5).ToString
                     'Write txt file with name and content derived from these strings
                     Loop
                End If
                dbReader.Close()
                dbConnection.Close()
Next
```

I am querying an Excel file using oledb. There are quite a few columns that a get data from for each row. This is running insanely slow. Is there a way I can optimize this? the count of the array list is approximately 23k.

Comment: you *could* read the entire file at once into a Datatable and then apply filters to work with parts of it at a time.  I'm not sure it would be faster, but it would be fewer DB ops

Comment: You don't need the `ToString` on top of `GetString`. I doubt that will make it faster: it's just redundant code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to only open the connection once then process the rows it returns as a recordset then close it.

So you could change the SQL to order the rows by sMatl_Num and to have a where clause that only selects the MaterialNumbers in alMaterialNumbers  (this might be an IN clause or a subquery - it depends on how many values there might be)

So having got a recordset you can loop through it writing out the rows for each MaterialNumbers , when the number changes write out to the next file...

Does this make sense.

Comment: It definitely makes sense to separate out the reading of the database from the writing of the file (memory permitting, but for only 23k records that would not appear to be an issue). Whether or not it will actually be faster is a different matter, but I think you have that part covered with the idea of using just one query to grab all the required data.

Comment: Yes it makes sense thank you! this block ran in about 9 minutes after using a solution like this. As opposed to several days I would say that is quite an optimization. Thanks again!

Comment: Great to know.  Please tick my answer and up arrow it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that for every `sMatl_Num` (I assume there are 23k?) you are opening an OLEDB connection, reading a record in, and then grabbing the fields one by one, writing them, then closing the connection. Opening and closing the connection, querying for a single material number while filtering other fields, and picking up data out of the fields returned is expensive.

This would probably be faster if you brought the entire recordset in at once (copy and paste), filter out `col3=null and col6=null` using autofilters or something, then just use native `vlookup` functionality to pull in `Col1` - `Col6` values. And it could still all be done in VBA.

The method you are using would be better suited for a single quick look up against a huge file. Like if you had a UI in Excel where a user would put in a material number and you would OLEDB over to your material master data and grab the attributes you want and return them to the UI. Once.